# How messy are male American persimmons?

Tags: fruit-trees

I know that I shouldn't plant kaki persimmons or seedling or female American persimmons near sidewalks and driveways, because the fruit will fall off and make a mess on the concrete.

What about a grafted male American persimmon? I've read that male persimmons often do have a few female or perfect flowers (leading, presumably, to a few fruits). How many such fruits? How much of a mess is it?

Comment: Impossible to say with any certainty, its anybody's guess. You might get no fruits, or you might get some. Probably best to select a different tree that won't drop fruit

Comment: let them drop, and worry about the mess later, if you need to at all